# Android Searchview with background hint

Tags: android

I am a newbie to android development, and would like to know if it is possible to create an search view with background hint, which changes automatically, as the user types in the search view box. for example, like in the Google search, where the grey part in the background gives the user the options of filling in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can read more about it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Answer (score 47):

You can add SearchView hint by following below :

```
search.setQueryHint("Google Search");
```

You can set Background color of SearchView by following below :

```
search.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: but this hint is only visible when I click on search Icon, Is it possible that hint can visible without click as we can see in edittext hint.

Answer (score 13):

Try something like this :

```
SearchView searchView = new SearchView(canvas.getContext());
searchView.setQueryHint("Type your text here");
searchView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

OptionCommand searchCommand = new OptionCommand();
searchCommand.setActionView(searchView);
searchCommand.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);
```

Answer (score 8):

These are the important lines which work together:-

```
       app:iconifiedByDefault="false"

       app:queryHint="@string/crop_name"
```

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to view a hint is by adding `queryHint="Search"` attribute to `SearchView` widget in XML.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/svSearchView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:queryHint="Search products.."
    app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvTitle"
    android:paddingLeft="14dp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add `SearchView` hint in two ways

1. By programmatically

   ```
   SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menuItem.getActionView();
   searchView.setQueryHint("Search Hint");
   ```
2. By using theme (`styles.xml`)

   ```
   <style name="MySearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView">
       <item name="queryHint">@string/search_view_hint</item>
   </style>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
searchView.setIconified(false);
```